# User Authentication for aws using Python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a project with Python(3.6) & Django(1.10) in which I'm using aws apis but I'm new to aws and don't know how to authenticate a user.

**My scenario is:**
I need to access user's aws resources like **projects list**, **buckets list** etc, for that, I need to **authenticate the user** when making a request to a particular API.

How can I do that in python?
I'm new to aws.So, please don't mind my question.

> Update:

Here's what i have tried:
**From views.py:**

```
def boto3_with_role(role_arn, session_prefix, external_id, **kwargs):
"""
Create a partially applied session to assume a role with an external id.
A unique session_name will be generated by {session_prefix}_{time}
`session` can be passed, otherwise the default sesion will be used
see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html
"""
sts = boto3.client('sts')
res = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName='{}_{}'.format(session_prefix, int(time.time())),
    ExternalId=external_id,
)
creds = res['Credentials']
return partial(boto3.session.Session,
               aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
               aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
               aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken']
               )

class AwsAuthentication(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    AwsSession = boto3_with_role('ARN_LINK_FROM_CUSTOMER', 'MyPrefix',
                                 'EXTERNAL_ID_FROM_CUSTOMER')
    my_session = AwsSession()
    client = my_session.resource('s3')
    for bucket in client.buckets.all():
        print(bucket.name)
        return HttpResponse('Your Bucket is: {}'.format(bucket.name))
```

> Now, it returns: **botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.**

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use boto3 or awscli to get access to those aws resource. but i didnt understand the user you talking about is your application user or third party user who trying to access resource of another user is it the case?

Comment: The user will authenticate itself from my application to aws, then my application will be able to access his resources!

Comment: Yes, you can but you have to have aws credential of that user.

Comment: Using boto3 python library, the 'official' aws library. You can store some environment variables in settings.py, then you should authenticate for any request you make.

Comment: the flow I want to build is as: I have a button in my app which says **Authorize with aws** when the user clicks on this button, he should be redirected to another browser tab where he needs to login to his aws account.

Comment: Can I get user's credentials in this way and then use these credentials when submitting API calls to aws?

Comment: This functionality does not exist for AWS.  It's not like Facebook or Twitter where you can create an app and then have uses grant access to that app through some auth flow.

Comment: But we can authenticate the users with aws to get access to their aws resources in our application!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why some others are suggesting that you cannot do this. This is completely normal and well-supported - many AWS account users allow third-parties to operate in the user's AWS account on behalf of the user. Any third-party monitoring service or cost analysis service, for example.

[Bad way] The first way is to simply ask the user for IAM credentials (an access key and a secret key). Your app can use those to access the user's AWS account. This is simple, but don't do it.

[Good way] A better way to do this is via cross-account access. You have an AWS account, and your user has an AWS account. You instruct the user to create an IAM role in his account with an appropriate IAM policy (the minimum set of permissions that your app needs) and you instruct the user how to allow your account to assume this role in the user's account - to do this you advertize the IAM policy needed and your AWS account number. The user can then create an IAM policy, create a role with that policy, then establish a trust relationship between your accounts so that you can assume that IAM role and operate in his account. For more, see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html).

Comment: Hi, @jarmod! first thanks for your answer, it make sense, but when user created the required IAM role for my app with our account id then how can i use his credentials from app via api?  can you help me with a code example, please!

Comment: I recommend that you set up two AWS accounts, configure an IAM policy, role, and trust relationship in account #1, and then use account #2 credentials to assume the cross-account role using http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role.

Comment: Which RoleArn & External Id I need to pass for assume_role?

Comment: External ID is optional and provides a little more security. The role ARN is what identifies the IAM role in the customer account. The user needs to share both with you. Typically you would ask the user to supply both the ARN and the external ID when they tell your system which IAM role you can use to access their account. You should review the tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: The user giving you access should use the AWS console to create the cross-account role using IAM | Roles | Create role | Another AWS account. That will prompt them for your AWS account ID (for the trust relationship). Once they've done that and shared the role ARN and external ID, any admin user in your account (or any user with explicit permission to assume that named role) should be able to assume that role. I would try this out with the awscli and remove your Django app from the picture until it's working.

Comment: I have created 2 aws accounts , one for my **app/developer** and one for my **customer/production**. Then in my **customer/production** account i have created an cross account IAM role with the account id from my **app/developer** account. After that i have provided external ID which i have used while creating IAM role in **customer/production** account and ARN from that account in the code.

Comment: OK, that sounds fine. Are you sure that you have correctly provided your app/developer credentials to STS when calling assume_role?

Comment: Yup, because I have copied arm and external id from customers‘ account, but what do you mean by app/developer credentials ? Please!

Comment: In order to call assume_role you need credentials. They are your app/developer credentials and they must have permission to assume the customer/production role. You’re using one set of credentials (in the dev account) to get a 2nd set of credentials (in the prod account).

Comment: Where I need to pass these credentials? as I have run **aws configure** command and provide access key and secret key of my app/developer account. Do I need to pass somewhere else?

Comment: now, it's returning another error: `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.`

Comment: OK so you fixed the earlier problem and are now correctly supplying credentials. Now you just need to create IAM credentials for your app to use (to replace the root credentials you are currently using). By the way, don’t use root credentials, especially not for your applications.

Comment: How can I do that, can you guide me, please!

Comment: Creating IAM users and applying policies is well documented. Use the IAM feature in the AWS console. Create an IAM user, download the credentials, and then attach a suitable policy.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality to have a user log into their AWS account to allow your application to access their AWS resources currently does not exist. A possible work around to consider is to provide the user with a direct link to creating an IAM role with a specific managed policy allowing a specific AWS account. You can then include that in your signup flow, and assume the role when you need to access resources in the user's account.

Example link:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#/roles$new?step=review&roleType=crossAccount&accountID=123412341234&policies=arn:aws:iam::aws:policy%2FAdministratorAccess&roleName=AdminAccessForServiceName

Comment: Hi, @Kenneth! it makes sense, What I understand is that: I will provide a link to the user to create an IAM role, but how can I use this for my scenario? can you write an example python code for that, please!

Comment: The following AWS documentation contains a Python example of how to assume a role and use the obtained credentials. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that the credentials you obtain from sts.AssumeRole call do expire after some time (in 15 minutes by default, but you can set it longer when doing the AssumeRole call, up to your current session max API session duration time, by default -- 1 hour) unless you refresh them.

If you need to automatically refresh the credentials, here I'm sharing my code I wrote after several hours of studying boto's code and trying to work around boto's dependency on file system and profiles.

Here I just used built-in boto's mechanism of caching and regularly refreshing the assumed credentials without touching any files:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import boto3
from botocore.credentials import (
    AssumeRoleProvider,
    AssumeRoleCredentialFetcher,
    DeferredRefreshableCredentials,
    CredentialResolver
)
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal


class CustomAssumeRoleProvider(AssumeRoleProvider):
    """
    Overrides default AssumeRoleProvider to not use profiles from filesystem.
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 source_session: boto3.Session,
                 assume_role_arn: str,
                 expiry_window_seconds: int):
        super().__init__(
            load_config=lambda: source_session._session.full_config,
            client_creator=source_session._session.create_client,
            cache={},
            profile_name='not-used'
        )
        self.expiry_window_seconds = expiry_window_seconds
        self.source_session = source_session
        self.assume_role_arn = assume_role_arn
        assert assume_role_arn, "assume_role_arn is required"

    def load(self):
        fetcher = AssumeRoleCredentialFetcher(
            client_creator=self.source_session._session.create_client,
            source_credentials=self.source_session.get_credentials(),
            role_arn=self.assume_role_arn,
            expiry_window_seconds=self.expiry_window_seconds,
            cache=self.cache,
        )

        return DeferredRefreshableCredentials(
            method=self.METHOD,
            refresh_using=fetcher.fetch_credentials,
            time_fetcher=lambda: datetime.now(tzlocal())
        )


def get_assume_role_session(
    source_session: boto3.Session,
    assume_role_arn: str,
    expiry_window_seconds=15 * 60
) -> boto3.Session:
    """
    Creates a new boto3 session that will operate as of another user.

    Source session must have permission to call sts:AssumeRole on the provided ARN,
    and that ARN role must have been trusted to be assumed from this account (where source_session is from).

    See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

    Uses internal session._session to hack it together, as I haven't found another way.
    """
    # must have .load() method to be used in CredentialsResolver.
    provider = CustomAssumeRoleProvider(
        source_session=source_session,
        assume_role_arn=assume_role_arn,
        expiry_window_seconds=expiry_window_seconds
    )

    # must have .load_credentials() method to be used in register_component()
    resolver = CredentialResolver([provider])
    new_session = boto3.Session()
    new_session._session.register_component('credential_provider', resolver)
    return new_session
```